# How to use group by in magento collection with join query

Tags: collection, magento-1, customer-group, join

In module's admin grid I am using this code to get collection and group them by customer id

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('referafriend/statistics')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

but here i have to use renderer and filter functions for customer info like name and email against each `entity_id`.
i want to join customer model with my module's table. for this i have written this code

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
 ->addNameToSelect();
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('refer' => 'table_name'),'refer.entity_id = e.entity_id'
          ); 
   $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id'); 
   $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

but it gives me this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in group statement is ambiguous
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: it  should be ->group('e.entity_id');

Comment: You should add this as an answer with some detail on why you need the `e.`

Comment: Sorry for this silly mistake. @AmitBera thanks for your help and please add this as answer so that question could be closed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to  add table name in `group by condition`.As you did `not added on conditions  table name` at table **group('entity_id')** so `query did not find columns name`

```
 getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

**Logic is:**

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME')
```

Comment: In addtion, if you need to group by multiple fields, the just add more -> group() clauses
->group('field1')
->group('field2');

Comment: I want order unique products using group by. I have 2 order with 2 same order item. Currently, it is displayed 4 rows in the grid. But I need 2-row using group by.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: `$collection = $object_manager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
            ['order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
            'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id and (if(main_table.parent_item_id IS NULL,main_table.price != 0.0000,main_table.parent_item_id IS NULL))',
            [
                'order_number' => 'order.increment_id',
                'order_store_id' => 'order.store_id',
            ]
        );`

Comment: I want to group by `parent_item_id` order wise.