# Magento 2 use group by in collection

Tags: magento2, collection, group

I've got a collection from the factory method `getCollection()`. The problem is that when I use `get_class_methods($class)` to list all the methods that the collection possesses I can't seem to find one which groups the records in the collection.
I found this [How to use group by in magento collection with join query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40337/how-to-use-group-by-in-in-magento-collection-with-join-query)
But I don't have the `group()` method in my collection class. How can I `group by` in that case ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot use group directly from the collection.
But each collection has an instance of `Zend_Db_Select` associated to it. This is the actual query that is going to be executed when the collection is loaded.
So you can use:

```
$collection = ....
$collection->getSelect()->group('group_field_here');
```

Comment: i have create a custom product attribute "sample_attribute" with drop down value i want to add group by in product collection but this gives unknown column how can i add group by in product collection