# Magento 2 How to set group by in Collection query?

Tags: magento2, collection, group

I have followed [Magento 2 use group by in collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113051/magento-2-use-group-by-in-collection)

I need to run below query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status= 'Enable' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC
```

In collection factory i have below code

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
           ->addFieldToFilter('id', $id)
           ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Enable')
           ->setGroupBy('posts_id') // I tried to use group() as well
           ->setOrder('id','desc');
```

How to set Group By on above collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with below code,

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
           ->addFieldToFilter('id', $id)
           ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Enable');

$collection->getSelect()->group('posts_id')->order('id DESC');
```

Comment: how can use count with group by clause .

Comment: @rakesh i have create a custom product attribute "sample_attribute" with drop down value i want to add group by in product collection but this gives unknown column 

how can i add group by in product collection

Comment: @VinitKumar did got any solutions, i'm also facing same issue