# Magento 2: Conver SQL Query to Magento Format

Tags: magento2, database, collection, query

In addition of [Magento 2 How to set group by in Collection query?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134847/magento-2-how-to-set-group-by-in-collection-query)

I have below query now.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM messages t1 WHERE t1.id = (select max(id) from messages t2 where t2.posts_id = t1.posts_id and t2.from_user_id = t1.from_user_id)
```

How can i convert it to Magento format as given answer

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
           ->addFieldToFilter('id', $id)
           ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Enable');

$collection->getSelect()->group('posts_id')->order('id DESC');
```

Comment: you have declared table name in alias of t1 and t2 are same in your case messages

Comment: Yes @Rakesh Please refer for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342424/mysql-multiple-group-by-with-desc-order-issue